# Deleted Users in FIM not matching UserProfileManager

Tags: user-profile-service, userprofiles, userprofilemanager

I'm looking in FIM (MIISclient.exe) and can see the daily sync summaries for each day. I notice the number of Deletes listed and it is about 15-20 on each day. However, when I use this snippet of code here to get the changes in the past day or even past few days, I get no deletes of user profiles. By this I mean that when I get the changes back, there are no deletes where the ChangeType is 'Delete' and the ObjectType is 'UserProfile'. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$query = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileChangeQuery
$query.Delete = $true;
$query.DistributionListMembership = $false
$query.UpdateMetadata = $false
$query.Add = $false;    

$d = get-date            
$query.ChangeTokenStart = 
  new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileChangeToken($d.AddDays(-5));
  $upm.GetChanges($query);
```

SOURCE: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/06/25/inside-the-sharepoint-2010-my-site-cleanup-timer-job/

Comment: What Management Agent is showing the deletes? The deletes may be happening within the AD MA or FIM Metaverse, not necessarily in the SharePoint UPSA.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar, but it is the one that starts with 'MOSS-' and has a GUID after it, which I understand to be the default one if not mistaken.

Comment: If this is the SharePoint MA, then why does the code listed above not retrieve those users? The code above pulls the changes from the last 5 days and none of those user profile deletes appear.

Comment: MA is not UPSA. MA resides solely in FIM. Can you tell us what kind of Deletes you're seeing?

Comment: Sure. When I click in MA for the MOSS connection, I see the Export Statistics listed below. It is here where I see the Adds, Updates, Renames, Deletes, and Delete Adds. The Renames and Delete Adds do not have links, but the other three (Adds, Updates, and Deletes) link to the Object Details window where I can click on individual users. The object type is user, and the modification type is delete. If I search for these users in UPA in CA, they come up under 'Profiles missing from import'.

Comment: Similarly, if I go to the Operations tab and check the syncs from the previous days and search for those users in UPA, they do not appear at all in Active or Profiles missing from import.

Comment: To follow up on the previous comment, some users do still appear in UPA, but as stated, others do not at all.